# how to access online mongoDB data using IOS

Tags: python, ios, mongodb, pyramid, database

My friend has a website built using Pyramid framework and using MongoDB to store data. If I want to build an iPhone app, how do I access the data from that database?

I know Obj-C and have built simple, iOS apps, but none of them used non-local data. I've googled but no good result returned. I just don't know where to start. Any good tutorial or sample code on the related issue would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as best practices go, you would not want to be accessing MongoDB (or any database) directly over the internet without appropriate security considerations.

The most straightforward option from iOS would probably be either add a [RESTful](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface) interface to your own application, or use a third party hosted solution that provides an API.  In either case I would recommend using https in addition to authentication, as the [MongoDB wire protocol](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Wire+Protocol) is not currently encrypted.

For iOS I would consider using the [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) framework as a handy helper.  It includes reasonable documentation and examples to get you started.